# MPD Download Problem

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

im triying download this: https://s3-dub-2.cf.dash.row.aiv-cdn.net/dm/2$0BUF7K2VT3IU0_lgY5I8MtbEnr0~/4a41/40a4/cba9/491e-8631-097e38e63dc5/b61f4b90-54ed-4b6e-8dc9-816b4cc58eab_corrected.mpd?encoding=hex&amznDtid=AOAGZA014O5RE If i use that as adress in a chrome windows says This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. and a lot of info about quality from video and audio.
If i try ffmpg give me error.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: donwload from tht link using ffmpg?

Comment: If you just want to download that manifest, you can also use `curl https://s3-dub-2.cf.dash.row.aiv-cdn.net/dm/2$0BUF7K2VT3IU0_lgY5I8MtbEnr0~/4a41/40a4/cba9/491e-8631-097e38e63dc5/b61f4b90-54ed-4b6e-8dc9-816b4cc58eab_corrected.mpd?encoding=hex&amznDtid=AOAGZA014O5RE`.

Not sure this is what you want to do, though. Hence my question.